# Vaadin: how to set up relation between two SQLContainers?

Tags: java, vaadin

I have two SQLContainers with the folowing data structure:

SQLContainer **SP**:

**FullUserName | tel | room**

SQLContainer **MT**:

**FullUserName | ComputerName | Domain | OS**

In my opinion, the foreign key of the both SQLContainers could be: **"FullUserName"** field?!

How can i set relation (reference) between these containers to get the finally view like this:

**FullUserName | tel | room | ComputerName | Domain | OS** 
?

Comment: maybe the documentation helps: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/sqlcontainer/sqlcontainer-referencing.html

Comment: thank you! But I allready try this. If i do: 
        MT.addReference(SP, "FullUserName", "FullUserName");
        MT.setReferencedItem("FullUserName", "FullUserName", SP); Last code string throw exception "com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer setReferencedItem
WARNING: Setting referenced item failed.
java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: Not sure if this helps: Did you try to use a FreeformQuery with a join?

Comment: Unfortunatelly i can`t to use "Join" statement, because the containers contains data from various SQL servers and tables. And i have to combine datasets on SQLContainer level (